# User input with deleting files

Tags: python

I am just learning Python and I am not sure why I am getting an error. I am getting an error at the `os.remove(p + ".txt")` part, What I am trying to do is get the users input for what file to delete so if anyone has a solutions please help. Thanks for looking!

```
def looping():
    if os.path.exists(p + ".txt"):
  os.remove(p + ".txt")
else:
  print("The file does not exist")
```

Comment: indent your code

Comment: You never define p or at least you don't in this code snippet. But you also need to indent your code properly.

Comment: I did not add p to the snippet, I can post full code if needed.

Comment: _I am getting an error_ What error? Add the full stack trace to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the code you don't specify what values P holds

```py
def looping():
    p = input("Enter the file name:")
    file = f"{p}.txt"
    if os.path.exists(file):
       os.remove(file)
    else:
       print("The file does not exist")
```

Also you have wrong identation.

Answer (score 0):

```
def looping(p):
    if os.path.exists(p + ".txt"):
        os.remove(p + ".txt")
    else:
        print("The file does not exist")

looping("new_doc")
```

This should be ok..provided pass `p` during your function call